# How to show the data added in Admin tool to front end in magento

Tags: magento-1.7

I have added some products in admin panel. In admin panel under manage products , those are getting displayed.

But these products are not displaying in front end. I am a newbie to magento. I looked into userguide. But of no use.

How to display the products in front end?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are couple of things which need to take care, when you create product in admin panel under manage products.

1. Under General sub tab, please check if you have changed your "Status" = "Enabled"
2. Under General sub tab, please check if your "Visibility" = "Catalog,Search". This will show the product under catalog and also you will get the product in front-end when you search.
3. Under Inventory sub tab, please check if you have added "Qty" > 0 and "Stock Availability" = "In Stock". Sometimes this creates problem to show the product in front-end.
4. Under Categories sub tab, please check if you have assigned the product to a category/subcategory under which you want to see your product.
5. Under Websites sub tab, assign to a website.